# Problem with moving the view when the keyboard is open

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem with the moving of text input and button when the keyboard is open. I am using the following code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

 deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }


    @objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {

        guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
            return
        }

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification || notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {
            view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height
        } else {
            view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }

    }
```

The problem occurs when I start typing in the text field, here are images before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EuWo.jpg and after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCKdz.jpg

I am sorry about the language it of files don't say anything spacial.

I want to know why this happens, is it possible to be because I am using CocoaPods - YoshikoTextField  in the grey text field ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are they simulator screenshots ? What is the problem precisely (what did you expect) ? Take care to toggle software keyboard (if testing on simulator) otherwise keyboard height may be wrong. You should also log keyboardSize with a print to check the value.

Comment: Just change if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification || notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {
            view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height
        } else {
            view.frame.origin.y = +keyboardSize.height
        }

Comment: yes, I am using simulator and toogle the keyboard but the problem remains, what I mean is the keyboard appears but when I start typing it is going up more like on the images, it is moving the fields up, more,

Comment: Your view moves upside because your view’s (initially) y origin is 0. 
After keyboard appears you set it to -346, your view’s origin is -346.  

Initially, self.view.frame.origin.y => 0.0

keyboardSize.height => 346.0

self.view.frame.origin.y = -346.0.

Solution: you need to add a scroll view instance on view and change content insets, otherwise to adjust your frame assign a constant value as according to your screen ratio.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundScrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
        adjustingHeight(true, notification: notification)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {
        adjustingHeight(false, notification: notification)
    }

    func adjustingHeight(_ isShow:Bool, notification:NSNotification) {

        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        let changeInHeight = (keyboardFrame.height + 20) * (isShow ? 1 : -1)

        backgroundScrollView.contentInset.bottom += changeInHeight

        backgroundScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom += changeInHeight

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```